# NASA Project Management Wall Chart

Tags: nasa, mission-design, risk-management

As an Undergraduate student and new to the field of Space mission design and systems etc, I want to know is there any detail explanation with examples of the jargon terms mentioned in the chart below? Can anyone  give details and an easy explanation of the data given in the Chart? I am learning this because I want to make myself familiar with space mission and management etc.

https://www.slideshare.net/CarlosDuarte39/nasa-project-management-wall-chart

**update:** much better quality [The NASA Program/Project Life Cycle Process Flow poster](https://spacese.spacegrant.org/uploads/Project%20Life%20Cycle/PPF_WallChart_color.pdf) See also [this discussion](http://thwink.com/sustain/glossary/AnalyticalApproach.htm)

Comment: Do you have a legible version of the chart? It's completely unreadable.

Comment: @OrganicMarble most if not all the words on the cart are also jumbled together as a big text dump on the page below the slide Searching the title found a nicer one, which I've added back into the post.

Comment: Thank you @uhoh for adding a readable version of this chart.

Comment: This is a very good question, but it is not a good question for this site. Answering this question would require a book. Multiple books. One such book is the [NASA Space Flight Program and Project Management Handbook](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20150000400).

Comment: There are several dozen, maybe even several hundred, of "jargon terms" on that chart. To make this work, it would be better if you asked about them one at a time, or perhaps one block at a time.

Comment: Comment: That chart is very, very waterfall. While this project management scheme is responsible for some very nice Mars rovers and some very nice pictures of Pluto, it also is responsible for projects that are decades late, that are a factor of ten over budget, and whose spacecraft are stuck with technology that was state of the art in the previous millennium. That said, I do hope the JWST does launch later this year, unfurl, and work.

Comment: @Autodidact you can also ask questions about the chart's genesis and history (Who are it's authors? Who directed it to be made? It's first use, or when it was first completed? Did it have a progenitor? etc.) See for example [When was the idea behind the DESCANSO Book Series first conceived, by whom, and what is its “mission”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22968/12102)